# what can cause node.js to print Killed and exit?

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js app that loads some data from Mysql into Redis when the app starts. It has been working fine up until we modified the data in Mysql.

Now it is just exiting with a `Killed` message.

I am trying to pinpoint the problem but is is hard to debug using the node-inspector as the problem doesn't appear when running in --debug.

I don't think my problem is in the data itself because it works on my local machine but doesn't work on my production box.

My question is, what causes the `Killed` message? Is it Node.js or is it in the Mysql driver or elsewhere?

Answer (score 73):

Check your system logs for messages about Node being killed. Your Node application might be using excessive memory and getting killed by the [Out-Of-Memory killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Comment: In my case, indeed, I see in /var/log/syslog: `Sep  4 16:21:32 hosting kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 29620 (nodejs) score 107 or sacrifice child` `Sep  4 16:21:32 hosting kernel: Killed process 29620 (nodejs) total-vm:1054732kB, anon-rss:136168kB, file-rss:0kB`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you're on a redhat system, that log is at `/var/log/messages`. Out of memory seems to be the problem for me too.

Comment: You are awesome, I literally started investigating process death in a elastic beanstalk machine with docker, looking at every log file generated by the system, when I decided to just ask Google, arrived at your post, and found the exact issue in messages.log. Thank you!

Comment: In that case what would solve the "out of memory killed process"? increasing memory? 
node --max-old-space-size=31744 dataTreatment.js #increase to 31gb   or so?

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez The out-of-memory killer is a kernel feature so it happens completely outside of node — if it happens it means you're running out of physical memory. You will likely need to _reduce_ the memory usage of processes you have running, not increase it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if Redis is what causes the Killed message but that was the cause of my problem.

I was sending to much data to multi because I originally thought that was the way to use pipelining (which is automatic).

Comment: did you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Docker, Node, Express and Prisma. This was happening during jest tests. Usually upping the memory had been helping using `node --max-old-space-size=4096 jest --runInBand`. However I had set my memory in `.wslconfig` to 4GB (trying to fix a different issue), so it couldn't use the extra memory noted in `max-old-space-size`. I set it back to 6GB and restarted Docker. That fixed the `Killed` issue.