# opa 1.0 : server does not start

Tags: exe, opa

I've just updated opa to 1.0. When I compile my opa files, I now get a .js file instead of a .exe file.

When I try to run this .js file (which is executable), I get the error "Killed".

What's worng ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it work if you do "node myapp.js" to start your app?

Comment: No, It fails with : module.js:337   execution of the application
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^     Export the CSS files embedded in the server to the file ...

Comment: I've tried to compile with --back-end ..flat, but I get the error : Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
MailMLRuntime referenced from /usr/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmlflat/stdlib.web.mail.smtp.client.opx/_build/cstdli
_2eweb_2email_2esmtp_2eclient.cmxa(Bsl_init_stdlib_2eweb_2email_2esmtp_2eclient)Reply

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "Killed" message is raised when the machine does not have enough memory.

cf: [what can cause node.js to print Killed and exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876136/what-can-cause-node-js-to-print-killed-and-exit)