# Node app, could an exception ever cause: SIGKILL?

Tags: node.js, forever

error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL

I'm running a node app on production with "forever".

Somewhat randomly, it shows these events in the logs, and this is causing requests with lots of backend processing that access a database to just stop, and you then have to re-request and hope that it finishes before the next SIGKILL.

My question is this: under any circumstances could an application exception cause a SIGKILL like this, in the context of forever?

I can't reproduce this locally in my development environment.

ENVIRONMENT: 
ubuntu 14.04
memcached
forever
node by itself (no nginx reverse proxy or anything)
connecting to a postgres database to query data

It's really hard to say for sure if the SIGKILL's are on an set interval, or if they are happening at a certain point in program execution.  The logs don't have a timestamp by default.  From looking at the output, I'd say it is happening somewhat randomly in program execution since it is at different points in the log file they appear.

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system your production and development environment are running?

Answer (score 4):

Check your system logs to see if the linux kernel's out of memory killer is sending the signal as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877331/266795)