# npm install not reading package.json

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

not sure what's going on but I have a box running on ubuntu through digital ocean and just cloned my git repo. I have a package.json that is correctly formatted (I've used it before) with ~20 dependencies.

the current dir where I cloned has chmod777 and when I

```
sudo npm install
```

It starts installing packages but node_modules doesn't get created nor do any of my node dependencies get pulled in from my package.json and there's a killed log at end of install attempt

Is there anywhere I can begin to debug this? I'm running the latest npm version (3.8.8) and node 5.8

edit: here's the output of npm install

```
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.10.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.4.4: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.1.14: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
extract:winston → gunzTar ▄ ╢█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
Killed
```

and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.10.2",
    "bower": "~1.4.1",
    "cheerio": "~0.20.0",
    "connect-mongo": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "growl": "~1.8.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-task": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-html2js": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-notify": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-script-link-tags": "^1.0.2",
    "log4js": "~0.6.33",
    "method-override": "~2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.4.7",
    "npm": "^3.8.6",
    "passport": "latest",
    "passport-openid": "latest",
    "request": "latest",
    "socket.io": "~1.4.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.5",
    "time-grunt": "~1.2.1",
    "winston": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of npm install?

Comment: I updated my op with that information

Comment: I might be out of memory... nvm that didnd't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the memory running out. you can look at /var/log/syslog to find out if it was node. found here: [what can cause nodejs to print killed and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876136/what-can-cause-node-js-to-print-killed-and-exit).

or try adding a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/npm-gets-killed-no-matter-what).

Comment: I needed to add a swap file. Fixed my issue. Thank you!